# Power BI Relationships - Can't determine the relationships between two or more fields

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

As part of our app we have an 'App Owns Data' Power BI embedded scenario. We have written a model with the intention that end users can connect to the Power BI model and write their own simple reports based on said model. 99% of the reports will be simple lists and the model is quite large, with a number of relationships - not your average star schema (we're basically trying to have it work like the old semantic models from SSRS).

It's *mostly* working well apart from when building a report that joins 4+ tables/views together. An example of our (very) cut down model is below...

[image: Relationships]

Users can build reports from fields in Occupancy, Property, Occupancy Person and Person tables, however, as soon as I add fields in from Person Contacts I get the following error

[image: Error]

There is obviously something I'm missing as back in SSRS this relationship would have been fine. How can I make it so that users will be able to build reports linking all these entities together?

Answer (score 2):

Just keep in mind, that all links "one to many" DAX engine converts to SQL `LEFT JOIN`. In your model you have multiple contacts for each Pearson, it means that DAX engine in fact converts `Person Contacts` table to a following table:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [PERSON CONTACTS]
  LEFT JOIN [PERSON]
  ON [PERSON CONTACTS].[Key]=[PERSON].[Key]
```

And that's it.

So, `[PERSON CONTACTS]` has link only with `[PERSON]` and only in one way. `[PERSON CONTACTS]` has no relations to any other table.

meanwhile `[Occupancy]` has Left join with all other tables except `[PERSON CONTACTS]`.

This is the reason why you get this error.

It can be several solutions. You can play with additional key fields and bothside links or DAX.

Comment: Ah OK - that's really useful, thank you. Would you mind elaborating on one of these solutions and how I might go about implementing it for the above example, please?

Comment: Hi, first add a result sample. Better as a flat table

Comment: Sorry, which table(s) are you needing example data for?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one column or two from 'PERSON CONTACTS', then I would resolve this with a DAX measure to concatenate the multiple 'PERSON CONTACTS' records, along these lines:

```
All Contacts =
CONCATENATEX (
    DISTINCT ( 'PERSON CONTACTS'[CONTACT DETAIL] ),
    'PERSON CONTACTS'[CONTACT DETAIL],
    ", ",
    'PERSON CONTACTS'[CONTACT DETAIL]
)
```

This will keep returning a single row for each Person, with their Contact Details concatenated into one cell.

If however, you need multiple columns from 'PERSON CONTACTS', I would turn its relationship with 'PERSON' into one-to-one.  This might require filtering the 'PERSON CONTACTS' data in the Query layer, e.g. only the "Primary" or "Most recent" record for each 'PERSON'

Comment: Sorry, but I need users to be able to show multiple rows from Person Contacts, not just one row

Comment: With that first measure, you would only use it in visuals where OCCUPANCY PERSON etc are required. You could build separate visuals using anything from the PERSON & PERSON CONTACTS tables, showing the multiple PERSON CONTACTS rows.